# How to clear my caches?

Tags: python

I am writing a program to benchmark my disk. I calculate the time it takes to write a file and read from the file on disk.

My file_read function looks like this:

```
def read(blockSize): #blockSize is in bytes, varies from 1 byte, 1 KB and 1 MB
    loops = 1048576 * fileSize / blockSize #number of iterations, fileSize is 100 (Mb)
    fp = open("foo.txt", "r")
    for j in xrange(0, loops):
        fp.read(blockSize)
    fp.close()
```

The throughput I am calculating is very high (close to 2 Gbps). I suspect this is because of the file being stored in my cache memory. Is there a way I can clear it to effectively benchmark my disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, [you can explicitly write to a special file to force the page cache to be cleared](http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches).

To do it in Python (because running a program to do it would cost a lot too), you'd do:

```
# On Python 3.3+, you can force a sync to disk first, minimizing the amount of
# dirty pages to drop as much as possible:
os.sync()

with open('/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches', 'w') as f:
    f.write("1\n")
```

Make sure you don't hold open handles to the file at the time you do this; an open handle to the file may prevent the cache for it from being dropped.

Another possibility that may work would be to use `posix_fadvise` to lie to the system so it drops the pages for you; you'd need to test to confirm, but you might be able to do something like:

```
def read(blockSize): #blockSize is in bytes, varies from 1 byte, 1 KB and 1 MB
    loops = 1048576 * fileSize / blockSize #number of iterations, fileSize is 100 (Mb)
    with open("foo.txt") as fp:
        # Lies to OS to tell it we won't need any of the data
        os.posix_fadvise(fp.fileno(), 0, fileSize, os.POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)
        # Changed our mind! Read it fresh
        os.posix_fadvise(fp.fileno(), 0, fileSize, os.POSIX_FADV_NORMAL)

        for j in xrange(loops):            
            fp.read(blockSize)
```

Like `os.sync`, the Python API wasn't introduced until 3.3, so you'd need to roll your own accessor with `ctypes` on earlier versions. Also note that as written, your code never seeks back to the beginning of the file, but reads far more data than the file contains. Did you perhaps mean to seek back to the beginning? You'd need to re-advise before each seek back.